# How can I as a student practice using Vertica?

Tags: vertica

I want to learn how to use HP Vertica, but the community edition it offers required that I have access to a cluster.

I don't own a server cluster, so is there any alternative or cheap hosting service I could use to try out Vertica?

Also, if such a way to try it out exists, which files should I download and install?

Comment: You could cluster a bunch of [VMs](https://community.dev.hp.com/t5/Vertica-Wiki/Configuring-Virtual-Machines-for-HP-Vertica-7-x/ta-p/226932).  It took some digging to find their [requirements](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/InstallationGuide/BeforeYouInstall/platformhardwarereqts.htm) page.

Comment: One Linux VM is enough; you don't need multiple nodes just to try it out (or even to run a small (<1TB) database for real).  You'd want multiple nodes for a production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community edition doesn't require that you have access to a cluster. You can run it on a single machine (VM on your personal copmuter). You need at least 3 nodes for fault tolerance.

You can see [my guide](http://vertica.tips/2014/08/20/installing-3-node-vertica-sandbox-environment-using-windows-and-virtualbox/) on installing a sandbox environment on Windows.

Comment: Excellent, and which of the many downloads on the my.vertica downloads page should I use to install it on Ubuntu?

Comment: The "Debian Linux 6 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" under "Download HP Vertica 7.1.1 Analytic Database Server"